# Databinding with Knockout JS not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js

I'm trying to bind my JSON object to a HTML div but none of the bindings seem to work. This is my current try on the subject. But I have tried using the template binding already. That resulted in an undefined error , but the object is correctly loaded because i always get it in the console.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var submissionViewModel = new SubmissionModel();
submissionViewModel.getSubmission().done(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(submissionViewModel, document.getElementById("submission"));
})
});

var SubmissionModel = function () {
var self = this;
//self.loading = ko.observableArray();
self.Submission = ko.observable(null);

self.getSubmission = function () {
    // Let loading indicator know that there's a new loading task that ought to complete
    //self.loading.push(true);

    return $.getJSON('/Submission/GetSubmission',
        function (data) {
            console.log("submission loading")
            console.dir(data);

            self.Submission = ko.mapping.fromJSON(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    );
}
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="submission" data-bind="with: Submission">
<span data-bind="text: SubmissionTitle"></span>
</div>
```

JSON

```
"{"
SubmissionID":"1be87a85-6d95-43aa-ad3c-ffa047b759a5",
"SubmissionTitle":"nog wat sliden",
"SubmissionDescription":"////",
"SubmissionFile":"TESTFILE  ",
"CreatedOn":"2015-09-02T21:10:54.913",
"SubmissionPoolID":"5af408f5-515c-4994-88dd-dbb2e4a242a2",
"SubmissionTypeID":1,
"CreatedBy":"a028a47d-3104-4ea4-8fa6-7abbb2d69bbd
"}"
```

I have been chewing on this problem for a few days now an I can't seem to get it to work. Could any of you point me in the right direction ?

Comment: can you add sample json reply in post actually i can't see data from link due to access restrictions on system.

Comment: I've added the json to the comment

Comment: `$.getJSON` returns json object. So you can do `self.Submission(ko.mapping.fromJSON(data));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In java-script to decode object inside string you need to use `JSON.parse` and make sure your object is `not` structured in such way *double quote inside double quote* .

**viewModel:**

```
var json = '{"SubmissionID":"1be87a85-6d95-43aa-ad3c-ffa047b759a5","SubmissionTitle":"nogwatsliden","SubmissionDescription":"--","SubmissionFile":"TESTFILE  ","CreatedOn":"2015-09-02T21:10:54.913","SubmissionPoolID":"5af408f5-515c-4994-88dd-dbb2e4a242a2","SubmissionTypeID":1,"CreatedBy":"a028a47d-3104-4ea48fa67abbb2d69bbd"}'
var ViewModel = function () {
    this.Submission = ko.observable();
    this.Submission(ko.mapping.fromJS(JSON.parse(json)));
    //you can also use ko.mapping.fromJSON(json) as jeroen pointed out   
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

working sample **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26579/)**

Comment: Your solution gives me Uncaught ReferenceError: json is not defined

Comment: `json` is nothing but `data` in your case under success. i just declared var json ="//your json"

Comment: Why do `JSON.parse`? Here [`this.Submission(ko.mapping.fromJSON(json));` works fine too](http://jsfiddle.net/boqw9q2f/)... (and is a bit more concise)

Comment: ooh yes you are right . i used `fromJS` so i used `parse` tough `fromJSON` does the trick (more concise) i'll add it my answer . cheers

Comment: More concise, and come to think about it also better backwards compatability for browsers that don't have `JSON.parse`.